# How to force JACKSON to use JSON Array when converting/serializing Java Arraylist?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class that I am trying to serialize using Jackson APIs. The sample class looks like this:

```
public class Pojo {

    String var0;
    Map<String, String> var1;

    public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    }

}
```

When I run this code with more than one entries in map, code works fine by generating output like: `{"var0":"blah","var1":[{"blah","blah"},{"blah","blah"}]}`

However, when the map has only one item, resulting JSON looks something like: `{"var0":"blah","var1":{"blah","blah"}}`

How can I force Jackson to generate something like: `{"var0":"blah","var1":[{"blah","blah"}]}`?

Comment: `Map<String, List<String>>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
Map<String, String> var1;
```

to

```
List<Map<String, String>> var1;
```